# array sorting alphabetizing

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

This is the code given:

```
// bubbleSort.java
// demonstrates bubble sort
// to run this program: C>java BubbleSortApp
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class ArrayBub
   {
  private long[] a;                 // ref to array a
  private int nElems;               // number of data items
//--------------------------------------------------------------
   public ArrayBub(int max)          // constructor
      {
      a = new long[max];                 // create the array
      nElems = 0;                        // no items yet
      }
//--------------------------------------------------------------
   public void insert(long value)    // put element into array
     {
    a[nElems] = value;             // insert it
  nElems++;                      // increment size
  }
//--------------------------------------------------------------
   public void display()             // displays array contents
  {
  for(int j=0; j<nElems; j++)       // for each element,
     System.out.print(a[j] + " ");  // display it
  System.out.println("");
  }
//--------------------------------------------------------------
   public void bubbleSort()
    {
    int out, in;

      for(out=nElems-1; out>1; out--)   // outer loop (backward)
     for(in=0; in<out; in++)        // inner loop (forward)
        if( a[in] > a[in+1] )       // out of order?
           swap(in, in+1);          // swap them
      }  // end bubbleSort()
 //--------------------------------------------------------------
   private void swap(int one, int two)
  {
  long temp = a[one];
  a[one] = a[two];
  a[two] = temp;
  }
//--------------------------------------------------------------
   }  // end class ArrayBub
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 class BubbleSortApp
   {
    public static void main(String[] args)
     {
    int maxSize = 100;            // array size
     ArrayBub arr;                 // reference to array
    arr = new ArrayBub(maxSize);  // create the array

  arr.insert(77);               // insert 10 items
  arr.insert(99);
  arr.insert(44);
  arr.insert(55);
  arr.insert(22);
  arr.insert(88);
  arr.insert(11);
  arr.insert(00);
  arr.insert(66);
  arr.insert(33);

  arr.display();                // display items

  arr.bubbleSort();             // bubble sort them

  arr.display();                // display them again
  }  // end main()
  }  // end class BubbleSortApp
 ////////////////////////////
```

I need to change this program to make it insert strings and display them in alphabetical order. This is what I have so far:

```
class ArrayBub
   {
   private String[] a;                 // ref to array a
   private String nElems;               // number of data items
//--------------------------------------------------------------
   public ArrayBub(int max)          // constructor
  {
  a = new String[max];                 // create the array
  nElems = "";                        // no items yet
  }
   //--------------------------------------------------------------
      public void insert(String value)    // put element into array
     {
     a[nElems] = value;             // insert it
    nElems++;                      // increment size
     }
 //--------------------------------------------------------------
   public void display()             // displays array contents
  {
  for(int j=0; j<nElems; j++)       // for each element,
     System.out.print(a[j] + " ");  // display it
  System.out.println("");
  }
//--------------------------------------------------------------
   public void bubbleSort()
  {
  String out;
   String in;

  for(out=nElems-1; out>1; out--)   // outer loop (backward)
     for(in=0; in<out; in++)        // inner loop (forward)
        if( a[in] > a[in+1] )       // out of order?
           swap(in, in+1);          // swap them
  }  // end bubbleSort()
//--------------------------------------------------------------
   private void swap(String one, String two)
  {
  String temp = a[one];
  a[one] = a[two];
  a[two] = temp;
  }
//--------------------------------------------------------------
     }  // end class ArrayBub
   ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class BubbleSortApp
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
   {
    int maxSize = 100;            // array size
    ArrayBub arr;                 // reference to array
    arr = new ArrayBub(maxSize);  // create the array

    arr.insert("hello");
    arr.insert("this");
    arr.insert("is");
    arr.insert("a");
    arr.insert("random");
    arr.insert("weird ");
    arr.insert("sentence");
    arr.insert("that");
    arr.insert("does");
    arr.insert("not");
    arr.insert("make");
    arr.insert("any");
    arr.insert("sense");

    arr.display();                // display items

    arr.bubbleSort();             // bubble sort them

    arr.display();                // display them again
}  // end main()
}  // end class BubbleSortApp
```

I have many errors. I am having a hard time changing the proper functions from variables to strings.  I understand once I get to a point in the code, but then I cannot use that for other functions etc...

Comment: If you have a specific question, please ask. But a general "fix all my errors in my code" will not work on SO

Comment: And typed in caps won't help.

Comment: @Ascalonian - I concur.  Thomas, you changed nElems to a string type but your comment directly after says that it is meant to contain a number.  Such a low level misunderstanding makes it hard to know where we can even help you short of rewriting all of your code for you.

Comment: Still newto this, thanks for the feedback.. I am working on becoming a better question asker :)

Comment: Actually, it wasn't quite all caps. Opie went out of his way to avoid capitalizing the first person singular pronoun.

Comment: @ThomasSpaulding - I recommend reading [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3):

```
Arrays.sort(a);
```

This will put array 'a' in alphabetical order